# How to use WAI-ARIA in GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, accessibility, wai-aria

I've created component in GWT but now I need to add accessibility to our components. We are using GWT 2.4. I.E How I can add role tag or aria tag in a DisclosurePanel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you reference GWT Guideline Documentation for ARIA - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideA11y

Also read through http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ARIAImplementationDetails

I am not exactly sure about adding role tag or aria tag in a DisclosurePanel. You can try and follow the principles GWT team use for Tree or Menubar which similarly show/hide data on interaction.

Comment: Thanks SSR, we've finally decided use the new version GWT 2.5 they've included a great support for accessibility in especial for ARIA. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideA11y